Cannot connect to Internet due to DHCP and DNS issue
I have an issue with our AD server DHCP and DNS configuration. Here are 2 situations:

Some devices have multiple different IP address for the same device in DHCP and DNS server. After deleting the records in DHCP and DNS and restarting, the Internet can be accessed again.

Sometimes with the steps above, they are still unable to access Internet. I continue repeating the process until the Internet can be accessed again.


For users that face issue occurred in situation (2), there are two odd situations: -
a) The DHCP address are recorded in DHCP server, but not on DNS.
b) My AD server could not ping the user PC, but they can ping my AD and access the Internet. DHCP and DNS server are synced but when issued ipconfig /all, the server listed for DHCP server is not the actual DHCP Server, for example: -

User PC address: 172.16.15.40
Gateway: 172.16.15.1
AD1: 192.168.3.3
AD2: 192.168.3.4
Server configured for DHCP: 192.168.3.3 (AD1)
DHCP server detected on user's PC: 192.168.3.4 (AD2)

My question is: -

what causes situation 1 and can it remedied by resyncing the details in DHCP server to DNS server? Or are there any steps I can take to resolve this issue?

How do I automatically update the host address in the AD DNS server in situation 2 (a)?

For situation 2 (b), why my user's PC detected the other AD server when the server itself didn't have a DHCP server configured?



how do you connect between 192.168 und 172.16?

You have endpoints with an unexpected DHCP server (192.168.3.4 (AD2)) and didn't even bother checking why it is receiving that? Obviously there is something in AD2 that is responding and probably has logs to review. Don't even bother with the other stuff until that mystery is solved.

If AD2 is the DHCP server and it is in the 192.168.3.x/24 network, your computer would not be receiving a 172.16.15.x address from AD2. What device connects your computer to AD2? Is it a SOHO router?

@GregAskew - I noticed that the server AD2 not configure DHCP as DHCP is only configured at AD1, the AD2 server act as a backup/ replica of AD1. I'll try to check on AD2's event viewer to verify if there is any DHCP services in AD2.
